# Is (*exptr)->cnt the same as exptr->cnt or (*exptr).cnt?

Tags: c, pointers

Is `(*pointer)->name` the same as `pointer->name` or `(*pointer).name`?

Comment: it's neither of those

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, the `a->b` operator is a shorthand for `(*a).b`.

```
struct foo {
    int b;
};

// the . operator is used when the struct object is NOT a pointer
struct foo a;
a.b = 42;

// the -> operator is used when the struct object IS a pointer
struct foo *a = malloc(sizeof *a);
a->b = 42;

// the same thing as the above example, but using the dot operator
(*a).b = 42;
```

The last example is dereferencing the `a` pointer (getting the object it points to), then using the dot operator to access the element `b` inside of it. Now let's translate your question.

```
// first one
(*a)->b; 
// would be the same as:
(*(*a)).b;
// that is:
(**a).b;
// which would be used in
struct foo **a ... ;
(**a).b; // get the first element of the array, access field b


// second example
a->b;
// is the same as
(*a).b;
// which is your third example
```

Answer (score 8):

No.

`(*pointer)->name` says “Get the thing that `pointer` points to. Get the structure that it points to and get the `name` member from it.” For this to work, `pointer` must be a pointer to a pointer to a structure. For example, it could have been declared as `struct foo **pointer`.

`pointer->name` says “Get the structure that `pointer` points to and get the `name` member from it.” For this to work, `pointer` must be a pointer to a structure. It could have been declared as `struct foo *pointer`.

`(*pointer).name` says “Get the structure that `pointer` points to. Get the `name` member from it.” It also must be a `pointer` to a structure.

(The only difference between the last two is that the second uses one operator in source code. The operations actually performed are the same.)

Comment: I think that an important distinction would be that in the first case, pointer is a `struct foo **`, while in the next two cases it's just a `struct foo *`.